# Private key is not loading upon loading from the Certificate Store

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, certificate-store

Authentication at RavenDB 4 needs to happen via certificates, which I created via Let's Encrypt. My *private key certificate* (.pfx) is stored in the Azure Key Vault. Because only password secured certificates can be uploaded, I made it secure via a password.

Upon loading the certificate via the usage of the *certificate thumbprint* it always shows it doesn't have a private key, thus failing the authentication process at my RavenDB instance. Both local via the Windows Certificate Store and at Azure.

I already tried to work with *private key certificate* without a password, I was then able to receive the private key. Yet, this isn't a solution as I cannot upload it to Azure.

```cs
var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 targetClientCertificate;
var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ravenDbSettings["CertificateThumbPrint"], false);
targetClientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certCollection[0].GetRawCertData(), ravenDbSettings["CertificatePassword"], X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); ;
```

I also tried it via the usage of the export I found somewhere

```cs
var targetTwo = new X509Certificate2(certCollection[0].Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, ravenDbSettings["CertificatePassword"]));
```

But then I got

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Key not valid for use in specified state'

My goal is to load the private key of the certificate and thus be able to authenticate at RavenDB.

Comment: Did you try `targetClientCertificate = certCollection[0];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use existing certificate stored in `certCollection` variable. Last line (where you fill `targetClientCertificate` variable) is not necessary and won't work if private key is not exportable. If code requires an existing instance of `X509Certificate2` class, then it stored in `certCollection` and will have associated private key link.

Comment: Didn't know about this 'security'. Took some time to fully test this. But this works. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

That probably has to do with the way you create your certificate.
Try this:

**Download openssl:** http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

**Generate cert and private key:** openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout YourName.key -out YourName.cert

**Generate pfx file:** openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey YourName.key -in YourName.cert -out YourName.pfx

**Import** YourName.pfx to the Store

Comment: OP asking about existing certificate, he didn't ask about new certificate generation.